# Return std::Vector<> by reference is slow?

Tags: c++, vector, std

I've tested this and passing by reference is about twice as slow compared to directly grabbing the member. E.G. -

```
class Mesh {

    public:
        inline std::vector<Vector3>& GetVertices() { return m_vertices; }

    private:
        std::vector<Vector3> m_vertices;
};
```

If I call GetVertices() very often each frame to grab the verts, it is much much slower than directly accessing m_vertices. But I want to keep m_vertices private. What can I do?

And why is it slower?

Comment: could you give test code, please?

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations on? That function should be inlined, which would make it just as fast.

Comment: Is the code calling GetVertices() capturing it into a new value? If so, you're making a copy, so returning by reference isn't helping you.

Comment: If you want to keep it private why do you have a GetVertices() method? That sort of destroys encapsulation.

Comment: Why do you return it by non-const reference? There is no point in `GetVertices` then

Comment: Note that g++-4.8 is growing a new optimization flag `-Og` that turns on some level of optimization while striving to keep the flow of your program closer to the source code than other optimization levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is going to inline that code and transform it into a direct access to the member (in any optimization level other than: *I want to run slow*)

Comment: Optimizations are off as it is running in Debug mode. Inline Function Expansion is: Default. Is it typical to have this setting in Debug, or should I change it?

Comment: @user1043761: Well, if you turn them on, you may get your debugger jumping around your code rather strangely. But be aware that some level of optimization is really important for performance in C++ and so you can't take the performance of your code with optimizations turned off as a true indicator of performance.

Comment: so it's possible that in debug mode inline functions aren't even inlined?

Comment: @user1043761: Of course, it's *debug* mode; the code is suppose to remain debuggable, and inlining a function would certainly screw that up. Is there meaning in worrying about speed with optimizations off?

Comment: @user1043761: The `inline` keyword (even the implcit one for functions declared in the class body) is never more than a hint. For such a simple function, that hint will be acted on, but not in debug mode for most compilers. And that's how it should be. Optimization frequently changes your code in really odd ways and can make it really hard to relate what's happening to what's going on in your code. For source-level debugging you want the compiler to have the boring simple, very slow interpretation in which there is always a direct correspondence.

Comment: ok well thanks everyone - testing in release shows it running just as fast now. Apparently I wanted it to run slow :)

Answer (score 0):

Are there any virtual functions that you're not showing? Maybe `Mesh` is a child class, and GetVertices() is a pure virtual function being called through the base class? That would slow things down slightly.

Another possibility is to return a *const* reference rather than a non-const reference, if you can.

Comment: It's not a virtual function, and returning a const reference doesn't change the speed.